# not able to save data,when i am using mutiple views in a coredata framework

Tags: iphone, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

i have started a new navigation based application with core data option checked
,so when i try to have multiple views and then save data ,the data is not saving and i getting error as
 "Unresolved error (null), (null)".

so please help me out.

Regards
Ranjit

Answer (score 0):

You should not write to Core Data from different views.
Make sure you do the saving in `viewWillDisappear`, so the new view that will appear can save without conflict.

That being said, your error seems to indicate that there is another problem. "Unresolved error" is your own string in the code, and (null), (null) indicates that the `NSError` object is indeed `null`. That means that the writing to the database has actually worked without error, and the problem resides in your program logic **or** in the code checking and displaying the changes.

Cheers,
Sascha

Comment: hey thanks Sascha for your answer..actually i am new to it and not understanding how to debug...if u dont mind..can i send u my project.

Comment: @Ranjit Perhaps it is best to just take the [Core Data Tutorial](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008305) from Apple. That's how I first wrapped my head around this.

Comment: thanks sascha for your reply....actually first i took a navigation based application,with coredata checked..so u know xcode does much of the work when we take a navigation based application..then what i did on click of add barbutton item..i created my own ui for user entry to store in the table.it works super..but now when on that user entry is coming via another page ,i mean on clik of add i open a menu page and here on click of cells i open a user entry page and try to save it..,in this case the data is not saving..so what might be th case

Comment: @Ranjit - It should be enough that you pass the `managedObjectContext` of your core data entity to the data entry controller and use that to save. How do you know it is not saving? You do not get an `NSError` when you call the save, right? Did you try looking at the database with Firefox and SQLiteManager or the command line tool? -

Comment: i am getting error as iits not able to find the entity,so how to solve this error,and i didnt get u on looking at the database with firefox and sqlite manager..